# How do i change query of MS Access 97 file using MS Access 2007

Tags: database, ms-access, ddl

I am adding a small feature in a program that uses access 97 db.

The change is to add a one single field in a table A.
There is one query which selects certain fields from that table. Now I need to add the field in that query too.

I have added the field using DDL SQL statment from query builder screen. But now I need to add the same field in query too...

So what can I do now to make the change in the field list of that query?

Note:

1. If i convert the 97 db to 2007 or other version I would have to change the code as well as the reporting tool also. So for small minor change I would like to leave it in same old format.
2. Any tool available for conversion back to 97 from 2007 would also be acceptable.

Comment: apart from the Access database what is your development platform ? Any chance it is vb6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then see this solution

[Redefine a query's SQL using VBA](http://www.devhut.net/index.php?lang=en&pid=0000000011#RedefQry)

Note that the `CurrentDb` variable refers to your 
DAO database object (the result of OpenDatabase)

You should be set.

Comment: Nice one link renick... it helped alot save me... thnx